# Execute PHP code returned by a cURL query

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to execute code that is returned by a cURL query.

The following code queries a page on my webserver:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://web.com/foo.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$res = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $res;
```

I would like to do so by only modifying the code in foo.php. 
I have tried returning PHP code as the result in foo.php with an eval() command but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Guys, I am not doing this for a public website. It is for a private project, I will be the only user. I know it's a huge security concern, I would never do something like this that would be live on the internet.

Comment: Needs more info. `eval` *is* the way to execute code received as strings, what exactly "doesn't seem to work"? Also: **don't do it**. `eval` is `evil`, and so on...

Comment: Wouldn't this fail horribly if there are any included/required scripts... references to a DB, external classes... pretty much anything of any interest? - and even if it did work, god only knows what *might* be in that code that is now running on your server! - Gah!

Comment: Re "I'll be the only user": That doesn't matter, you simply don't do it. :) It opens an attack vector (a huge one) into your system. Even if the chances of somebody exploiting that vector are minimal, it's a bad habit to fall into. *Especially* private projects are the perfect chance to *do it right*. Professional programmers are often enough forced into sub-optimal solutions for political reasons, don't go there by yourself if you don't have to. `</2cents-and-some-change>` :)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is a terrible idea for security and you shouldn't do it.

That said

- ensure that the `allow_url_fopen` option is permitted in your php.ini, or set it using [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set)
- ensure that web.com is actually returning PHP code, not *executing* the PHP code and returning the output - that won't give you anything useful to run (unless the PHP code is generating *other* php code as output, but then you're really getting too far down the rabbit hole)
- then just `include "http://web.com/foo.php"`

Now, to reiterate, don't do it unless you're really very sure of yourself, or you really like having your site hacked.

Comment: That would require me to get rid of the cUrl code above and use include instead. My goal is to do this only through cUrl (and not through include)

Comment: Why?  If you're determined to be insecure, then being insecure this way is much easier than being insecure using curl.  Both approaches are a bad idea, and this one is no worse security wise, but much easier implementation wise.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `eval` does not need the leading `<?php` to work.
An alternative to `eval` would be to write the code into a file and then include said file.

Also, make sure you set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to true, otherwise, you might just display the code.

Comment: How does CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER work? I can't find much documentation on that option. Does it save the result in a variable (instead of outputting it directly) ?

Comment: `CUROPT_RETURNTRANSFER` makes it so that `curl_exec` returns the response as a string instead of writing out directly to the client (browser, console).

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: THIS IS A HORRIBLE IDEA. I HIGHLY RECOMMEND THAT YOU USE SOME OTHER APPROACH.

Im going to guess that the file son your server are being interpreted by the server they are on so you get the PHP parse response. Try renaming them to something else like `.phtml`. Or turn PHP off on the remote server. Then it should just be a matter of:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://web.com/foo.phtml");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$parsed = eval($res);

// echo or do whatever with $parsed
```

But as i said in my disclaimer, and everyone commenting answering this question has said... This is a securoty risk and even beyond that has all kinds of gotchas. If you ellaborate on why it is you want to do this we can probably find a better solution that doesnt make Jon Skeet cry.